# Comparing dipole moments of hydrogen halides

Tags: dipole

How can we compare dipole moments of halide ions?

As we go down the group, the induced charged hydrogen decreases as electronegativity difference between hydrogen and corresponding halogen decreases but the sepeartion between the poles of dipoles increases and since dipole moment is given by, $$\mu=qd$$

the $q$ factor and $d$ factor contradicts each other, so how can we do comparisons in such cases?

Comment: Go and measure $q$ and $d$.

Comment: Or look up the data on the compounds in Wikipedia. Hint: the maximum is where you probably think it is.